# laravel Auth::check not working in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an API, some routes could be accessed with or without auth.

The user can open pharmacy, and if he is logged in he may favourite it or not; if he is not logged in, it will be 0.

This is my model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'city_id', 'block_id', 'address', 'contact', 'image', 'status', 'user_id'];

protected $appends = ['favourite'];

public function getFavouriteAttribute()
{
    //return \auth()->id();
    if (\auth()->check()) {
        return (FavouritePharmacy::where('user_id', \auth()->id())->where('pharmacy_id', $this->id)->count() == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

The problem is that the `favourite` attribute always return 0.

When I check the auth, it returns `null`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I am trying to check auth() from api. so I should add 'api' giurd

```
\auth()->check('api')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like `auth()->check()` (remove the ' \ ' ) or `Auth::check()`, so it will be:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
        return (FavouritePharmacy::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('pharmacy_id', $this->id)->count() == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

And import Auth at the top of the model,

`use Auth;`

Comment: the same thing, return null

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is the auth middleware itself, make sure that whatever route or page that calls this method has an auth middleware defined for it.